# How to create a rectangle thin from top?

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I am relatively new to Inkscape and I want to create a rectangle which is thick from bottom and thin from top like a tower. How can I do that? Plus a good Inkscape book or ebook or tutorial would be appreciated.

Comment: What you want is to draw a polygon using the pen tool (since it's not really a rectangle). There are lots of [tutorials](https://inkscape.org/en/learn/tutorials/) on Inkscape's website, and the user manual is fairly comprehensive.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Sarthak Srivastava! If you need to draw a trapezoid, you can start from a rectangle, [convert](https://inkscape.org/it/doc/shapes/tutorial-shapes.html) it to a path and [scale](https://inkscapetutorials.org/2013/09/10/inkscape-pro-tip-resizing-or-rotating-selected-nodes-of-a-path/) the lower side. I suggest you to read [this](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/) and update your question with your efforts. Or write by yourself an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you mean by

> thick from bottom and thin from top like a tower

but I'm assuming you want to achieve either one of these:

[image]

#### Case 1:

- Draw a rectangle, let's say `300x200`px with a stroke of `10`px.
- Select the rectangle and in the menu choose "Path" > "Convert stroke to path" (or hit `Ctrl+Alt+C`).
- Now enter the "Edit paths by nodes" mode (hit `F2`). Pick the top left node of your rectangle. Move it down and right (with the arrow keys) until the stroke on the left side of the rectangle has narrowed down to your liking.

[image]

- Repeat the (inverted) procedure on the top right corner of the rectangle.

*There you have it*: A rectangle with thick stroke on the bottom and thin stroke on the top.

#### Case 2:

- Draw a rectangle, let's say `300x200`px with a stroke of `10`px.
- Select the rectangle and in the menu choose "Path" > "Object to path" (or hit `Shift+Ctrl+C`).
- Now enter the "Edit paths by nodes" mode (hit `F2`). Pick the top left node of your rectangle. Move it to the right (with the arrow keys).

[image]

- Repeat the (inverted) procedure on the top right corner of the rectangle.

*Voilà* - a beautiful trapezoid.